# autossh, systemd, ssh tunnel for MySQL

Tags: mysql, systemd, ssh-tunnel

I want to use `systemd` to create an SSH tunnel to allow access to `MySQL`. I want this connection to be available to other users after I log out. I know I've got a problem because the syslog (Ubuntu 18.04LTS) is full of messages telling me that `autossh` is constantly re-starting ssh (see below). Consequently, usage of the SSH tunnel fails.

Here's what I'm trying to do.  There is an MySQL server on system `Y.example.com`. `MySQL` docs suggest that SSH Tunnel is best secure way to allow connection from another machine. I have never created a tunnel before, but it looked like fun.

**This part works**

The machine with the apps that want to pull from `MySQL` is called `X`. I found out I can run the following (as user autossh) interactively to open the tunnel:

```
$ ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 autossh@Y.example.com \
-i /home/autossh/.ssh/PJ-nopass -NnT
```

I created a user `autossh` on both systems to facilitate this.  After that, on X, I can be any user and access the MySQL server as if it were on that system. To verify MySql access from X, I run

```
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u testacct -p testdb
```

Wow. Amazing. So far as MySQL is concerned, I'm logged in on `Y`.

Then I said to myself, "this is not adequate because the tunnel will break down when I log out".  I did not find a solution for that at first, but I found related issues dealt with by `autossh`.  Perhaps fitting SSH into a `systemd` configuration would have been sufficient. However, I did not understand that. When I found the `autossh` pages, they were about wrapping that into a `systemd` service at first. There might be some good reasons to wrap these together (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423795/73319)

Autossh is basically a script that restarts if an ssh connection fails. It is not a daemon, but seems quite a bit like one.  Running this interactively also successfully creates the SSH Tunnel (same effect as running `ssh` command above, AFAICS):

```
$ autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" \
-L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 autossh@Y.example.com -i \
/home/autossh/.ssh/PJ-nopass -NnT -f
```

Now, how to make that run after I log off? That is the million dollar question. The suggestion was that I should wrap this into a systemd service.  Here were the sources where I found that advice:

https://dadhacks.org/2017/11/08/set-up-autossh-with-systemd/

http://logan.tw/posts/2015/11/15/autossh-and-systemd-service/

https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/

Keeping this as simple as possible, here is my service file in /etc/systemd/system:

```
[Unit]
Description=autossh
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=autossh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 autossh@Y.example.com -l autossh -i /home/autossh/.ssh/PJ-nopass -NnT -f
Restart=always
RestartSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Here is the symptom of the problem I want to fix**:  the SSH tunnel keeps closing and opening, and it does not stay open long enough to use.  The /var/log/syslog was full of this noise (thousands of these):

```
Jun 15 21:05:23 X systemd[1]: autossh-mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 15 21:05:23 X systemd[1]: autossh-mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6765.
Jun 15 21:05:23 X systemd[1]: Stopped autossh.
Jun 15 21:05:23 X systemd[1]: Started autossh.
Jun 15 21:05:23 X autossh[38881]: port set to 0, monitoring disabled
```

This appears EVERY MINUTE. The user effort to access the database mostly fails.

I googled around some more (dangerous, you notice from my previous admissions...) and came to advice that the problem with my systemd service file was the child process was running and finishing, causing a restart.  I don't understand how that could be with `autossh`.

One fix (which works!) is to add this into the systemd service file

```
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Apparently, that's not great because systemd does not notice when the program fails.  Oh, well. Why did it "work" and why did I need it at all?

This seemed to run well last Friday, but I came in on Monday and the logs were full of that noise.

Version info:

autossh              1.4e-4
systemd              237-3ubuntu10.4 amd64
openssh-server       1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3

Comment: Hm. Overnight, I realized I have "-f" putting the ssh connection in the background. Is that causing systemd to think the program finished, causing all restarts?

Comment: Yup, `-f` is the culprit. Simple services run on foreground (from systemd's point of view), and systemd takes care of daemonizing them. For services that forcibly runs on background you should set `Type=forking` so systemd is aware of this and can monitor the spawned child pid. Not the case with SSH tho, and its `ssh -f` option is meant just as a convenience for quick terminal usage.